# Subfolders open themselves in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, xcode9

In Xcode 9, when creating a new folder or any file, I have a full list of all the subfolders and files, the project was created in Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235). Also I'm working on a project that was created in Xcode 8, there is no such problem. I think this is a bug, if not then how can I disable this feature? Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. All my subfolders keep opening after every build. It's really annoying and hoping someone has some insight into this.

Comment: @Alexsander did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @user2363025 Unfortunately no. This problem also appears after today's update. Xcode Version 9.1 (9B55)

Comment: Still in the Xcode 9.1. This is really frustrating since it creates a mess every single time you build a project or make a change in files hierarchy.